# Wifi card not working, rfkill hard blocked, modprobe doesnt work, reinstalled legacy drivers, rebooted, etc

Tags: linux, fedora, kernel, drivers, thinkpad

This is my first post, so please tell me if I have anything to correct in regards to where I'm posting, the format, or anything else

In short, my wifi card, an Intel Centrino Wireless-N 2200, as outlined with `lshw -class netowkr`, has stopped working, and I honestly don't know how to fix it. I've provided the outputs of several commands that might help in troubleshooting this issue, so please let me know if there is any other information needed.

This is on a Thinkpad x230, and pressing Fn + F5 to toggle the wifi has not worked.
I saw mention that turning on airplane mode on Fedora is a common bug that can result in breaking the wifi capabilities.

Things I have tried:
-`sudo rfkill unblock all`
-rebooting
-upgrading from kernel 5.5.6 to 5.5.7 and 5.5.8. The issue is present in all kernel versions
-`sudo rmmod iwldvm`, followed by `sudo modprobe iwldvm`. After this, rfkill shows it is not hard blocked, but any attempts to enable wifi fail
-Using the GUI to enable wifi
-Disabling wlan in BIOS, then re-enabling
-Enabling all wireless related settings in BIOS. Wifi working does not seem to be tied to if   bluetooth and wwan are enabled
-followed [this link](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html), installed the related driver, and ran `cp iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode /lib/firmware` as outlined in the driver's attached README

Here's my specifications as listed in system settings

```
KDE Plasma Version: 5.17.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.67.0
Qt Version: 5.13.2
Kernel Version: 5.5.8-200.fc31.x86_64
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 4 × Intel® Core™ i5-3230M CPU @ 2.60GHz
Memory: 7.6 GiB of RAM
```

output of `lsmod | grep iwldvm`

```
mac80211              991232  1 iwldvm
iwlwifi               339968  1 iwldvm
cfg80211              843776  3 iwldvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
```

output of `lspci`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville) (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation QM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd PCIe SDXC/MMC Host Controller (rev 07)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2200 (rev c4)
04:00.0 USB controller: Fresco Logic FL1100 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 10)
```

output of `rfkill list`

```
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

output of `sudo lshw -class network`

```
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: enp0s25
       version: 04
       serial: 3c:97:0e:e5:70:44
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.13-3 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:34 memory:f2600000-f261ffff memory:f263b000-f263bfff ioport:6080(size=32)
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Wireless-N 2200
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: c4
       serial: f6:94:19:7d:1f:d8
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.5.6-201.fc31.x86_64 firmware=18.168.6.1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:38 memory:f1d00000-f1d01fff
```

output of `iwconfig`

```
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp0s25   no wireless extensions.
```

output of `ifconfig`

```
        ether 3c:97:0e:e5:70:44  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 20  memory 0xf2600000-f2620000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 172  bytes 14234 (13.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 172  bytes 14234 (13.9 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

output of `dmesg | grep iwlwifi`

```
[   33.276721] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 18.168.6.1 op_mode iwldvm
[   33.400753] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUG enabled
[   33.400755] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUGFS enabled
[   33.400756] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEVICE_TRACING disabled
[   33.400757] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 2200 BGN, REV=0x104
[   33.413914] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: reporting RF_KILL (radio disabled)
[   33.413929] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio.
[   33.453658] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
```

output of `rfkill list` after running `sudo rmmod iwldvm` and `sudo modprobe iwldvm`

````
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
    ```

output of ```dmesg | grep iwl``` after running ```sudo rmmod iwldvm``` and ```sudo modprobe iwldvm```
```[   33.272948] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[   33.276721] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 18.168.6.1 op_mode iwldvm
[   33.400753] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUG enabled
[   33.400755] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUGFS enabled
[   33.400756] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEVICE_TRACING disabled
[   33.400757] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 2200 BGN, REV=0x104
[   33.413914] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: reporting RF_KILL (radio disabled)
[   33.413929] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio.
[   33.437715] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-agn-rs'
[   33.453658] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
[ 1445.153172] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUG enabled
[ 1445.153174] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUGFS enabled
[ 1445.153175] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEVICE_TRACING disabled
[ 1445.153177] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 2200 BGN, REV=0x104
[ 1445.166854] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio.
[ 1445.190566] ieee80211 phy1: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-agn-rs'
[ 1445.207598] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
[ 1445.237679] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio.
[ 1445.249022] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -132
[ 1445.249053] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Unable to initialize device.
[ 1445.262729] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio.
[ 1445.275168] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -132
[ 1445.275201] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Unable to initialize device.
[ 1445.400046] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -132
[ 1445.400079] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Unable to initialize device.
[ 1445.426083] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -132
[ 1445.426116] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Unable to initialize device.
[ 1456.015945] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -132
[ 1456.015979] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Unable to initialize device.
[ 1456.042995] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -132
[ 1456.043028] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Unable to initialize device.
[ 1466.007525] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio.
[ 1466.019910] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -132
[ 1466.019944] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Unable to initialize device.
[ 1466.033553] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio.
[ 1466.045896] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -132
[ 1466.045929] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Unable to initialize device.
[ 1476.003372] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio.
[ 1476.014742] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -132
[ 1476.014768] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Unable to initialize device.
[ 1476.028464] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio.
[ 1476.040817] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -132
[ 1476.040849] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Unable to initialize device.
[ 1486.012307] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio.
[ 1486.024693] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -132
[ 1486.024725] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Unable to initialize device.
[ 1486.038299] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio.
[ 1486.049637] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -132
[ 1486.049669] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Unable to initialize device.
[ 1496.012191] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio.
[ 1496.023517] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -132
[ 1496.023550] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Unable to initialize device.
[ 1496.037163] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio.
[ 1496.048489] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -132
[ 1496.048519] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Unable to initialize device.
````

after restarting, rfkill gets reset to `hard block: yes`

Comment: Have you checked the [hardware switch](https://i.imgur.com/MKVvshp.png)?

Comment: @Freddy As I explained in my post, the Fn + F5 key does not toggle was not effective. The Thinkpad x230 does not have any other hardware switch

Comment: You don't have the wireless switch on the left side below the ExpressCard slot? [Left side view - ThinkPad X230, X230i](https://support.lenovo.com/il/en/solutions/pd025115)

Comment: @Freddy Oh, my apologies. I did not know about that switch. It was on this entire time, but switching it back and forth a few times seemed to fixed it. Sorry about my flippant response. Thank you so much!

Comment: No worries. If that really solved the issue, please write a short [self-answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) 
and accept it after two days to mark the question as resolved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the wireless hardware switch was enabled this whole time, switching it on and off a few times fixed the issue